# How to download a JSON file from Amazon S3 via CORS?

Tags: javascript, json, amazon-s3, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to enable my javascript code to download json files from my Amazon S3 account. My S3 CORS configuration looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>https://www.example.com</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

My relevant javascript code (served from https://www.example.com for this example) looks like this:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

req.open('GET', 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/myfile.json', true);
req.withCredentials = true;
req.onload = function () { ... };
req.onerror = function () { ... };
req.send();
```

Note that this example is specific to browsers that support the "withCredentials" field.

The request fails with status 404. I've verified that the S3 json file being requested is indeed accessible and displays properly when its url is entered in a browser.

Does anyone see what I'm missing?

**Update:** I created a simple, new javascript file to do further testing, and the test code worked fine. So, the example code shown above works, I just need to determine how my actual code is different. Sorry for the unnecessary distraction caused by my question, but hopefully the code example will prove useful to someone down the road.

Comment: Is it because you're configuring CORS on HTTP but you're making the request on HTTPS?

Comment: @Mike Feltman, Both my domain and Amazon S3 use https. I've now clarified my question to show that. Thanks.

Comment: <CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/"> vs. req.open('GET', 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/myfile.json', true); is what I was referring to.

Comment: If it’s 404 it seems like it’s not a browser/CORS problem at least—since the browser is what enforces CORS policy. CORS errors generally don’t manifest as 404s. Anyway, comparing your code to http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html#how-do-i-enable-cors it all seems right and nothing is obviously missing. It would be nice if the Amazon docs for this explained what a failure case actually looked like, and provided troubleshooting info…

Comment: Have you tried it in several browsers to see if you get the same (404) response in all? Have you looked at the devtools console to see if anything interesting is getting logged?

Comment: Incidentally, I’m not 100% certain what `AllowedHeader` does but I assume it sets the CORS `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header and if so, its value can’t be `*` but instead must be an explicit list of headers names. [Per the spec](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-new-header-syntax) the only `Access-Control-` header that allows `*` as a value is `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

Comment: Good point, @sideshowbarker. I added `AllowedHeader` while trying to figure out how to solve my problem. `AllowedHeader` appears in the [S3 CORS doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html) in their example, so I tried it hoping it would solve my problem. Looking at the doc again I see their example only uses `AllowedHeader` for PUT, POST, and DELETE, not GET. So, now that I have everything working, I removed `AllowedHeader` from my CORS configuration and everything still works fine. I have updated my example here to reflect change. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: For completeness sake: If your S3 CORS is not working due to status code 403 then check to be ensure your S3 files are set to "public".